# term <C:\Users\myuser\Desktop\New folder\abc.def.ps1> is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable

Tags: powershell, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I am creating a jenkins pipeline with stages. In this pipeline stages calls the powershell file and execute the needful and completed the task.

My issue here is, when executing the below code in one configured agent its working fine and in another agent when i trigger this pipeline job "term  is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable" error message is thrown in console. I am not sure why this stuff is happening.

```
pipeline{
    agent { 
        label 'abc' 

    }
        stages{
            stage("SETUP"){
                steps{
                    powershell returnStatus: true, script: "${filepath}\\abc.def.ps1 ${p1} ${p2} ${p3} ${p4} ${p5}"
                }
            }
            stage("BUILD"){
                steps{
                    powershell returnStatus: true, script: "${filepath}\\ghi.jkl.1.ps1 ${p1} ${p1}"
                    powershell returnStatus: true, script: "${filepath}\\ghi.jk1.1.ps1 ${p1} ${p1}"

                }
            }
        }
    }
```

**Error message**

> term 'C:\Users\myuser\Desktop\New folder\abc.def.ps1'
>   is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable 
>   program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.

Note 1: The same file is being configured using jenkins normal job and working fine

Note 2: The same is working fine in my another agent machine

Comment: If the error contains `abc.def.ps1on.notification.ps1` as the file name, then the problem isn't with PowerShell but with how jenkins constructs the `script` string - might be worth updating the question title

Comment: Updated the error message. A typo error in the message. Moreover when i run in my another agent there is no error

Comment: I think you want `$filepath`

Comment: @js2010 this is correct i am seeing the right path in console

Comment: Not `$(filepath)`

Comment: @js2010 when i use ${filepath}\\abc.def.ps1, i am getting the path C:\Users\myuser\Desktop\New folder\abc.def.ps1 as expected. correct me if i am wrong

Comment: My bad.  I thought it was parentheses.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue is now resolved. The reason is because of the network drive mapping. On the time of execution there was no mapping to the network drive where the ps1 files are available